# Run a Win32 app from bash (through WINE) without calling WINE explicitly

Tags: linux, wine

For purposes like compiling GCC from source and being able to do a "profiledbootstrap", I need to be able to use the stage1 compiler (Windows executable) on from Linux.

What would be ideal: some setting/command that lets me do `gcc.exe` from bash and have it work (load WINE automatically)

What would be less than ideal but equally fine: tell the GCC build system to call the bootstrap compilers through WINE (ie prepend "wine " to all call to win32 applications).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use binfmt_misc in order to [invoke Wine](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Wine#Using_Wine_as_an_interpreter_for_Win16.2FWin32_binaries).